# jquery $.each incorrect binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='a'>A</div>
<div id='b'>B</div>
<div id='c'>C</div>
<div id='d'>D</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var first = [$('#a'), $('#b')];
var second = [$('#c'), $('#d')]

var everything = [first, second];
for (var i=0; i<everything.length; ++i) {
    var current = [];  
    for (var j=0; j<everything[i].length; ++j) {
      current.push(everything[i][j]);
    }
    $.each(current, function(i,d) {
      d.hover(function() {
        $(current).each(function() { this.css('background-color', '#00FF00') });

      }, function() {           // Hover out
        $(current).each(function() { this.css('background-color', 'white') });

      });
    });

  }
```

This code is a little strange because I took my original code to nerf it down to something presentable here.

Why is C,D highlighted when I hover over A,B?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4rSj/4/

**EDIT**

Desired Behavior: I would like A,B to highlight when I hover over A or B and C,D to highlight when I hover over C or D

Comment: just a silly question: why you just don't use the `:hover` css pseudoclass to hover your elements?

Comment: because I have to do other things such as highlight all the elements of that group rather than just that particular element. i.e. If I hover over A i want to have both A and B highlighted

Comment: You haven't defined the expected behaviour in the question. Do you want A and B to highlight when the user hovers over either A or B, and C and D to highlight when the user hovers over either C or D?

Comment: It’s because `current` holds references to `#c` and `#d` when the hover handler function is executed … use a variable _inside_ of your each loop to create a scope that preserves the current value, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C4rSj/5/

Comment: Bravo @CBroe. Wish you had an answer so I can check you off

Comment: @CBroe
That can be an answer.

Comment: I think your code is too long and redundant, you can always find a shorter way, such as like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/C4rSj/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because `current` holds references to `#c` and `#d` when the hover handler function is executed.

Use a variable inside of your each loop to create a scope that preserves the current value, like this:

```
$.each(current, function (i, d) {
    var _cur = current; // local variable to preserve value of current within the scope of this function
    d.hover(function () {
        $(_cur).each(function () {
            this.css('background-color', '#00FF00')
        });
    }, function () { // Hover out
        $(_cur).each(function () {
            this.css('background-color', 'white')
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4rSj/5/

Answer (score 0):

though you have already an answer, I would probably change the code to make it better for reuse:

HTML:

wrap all group elements in a div and use `data-group` to set the group

```
<div class="grouping">
  <div id='a' data-group="1">A</div>
  <div id='b' data-group="1">B</div>
  <div id='c' data-group="2">C</div>
  <div id='d' data-group="2">D</div>    
</div>
```

then use a simplify version of your code, where you add/remove css classes instead of hardcode the values:

```
function setGroups() {  
  var groups = [];
  $(".grouping > div").each(function(i, elm) {
    var g = $(this).attr("data-group");

    if(!_.contains(groups, g)) {          
      $(elm).parent().find("[data-group=" + g + "]")
        .hover(function() {
          $(elm).removeClass("out").addClass("in");
        }, function() {
          $(elm).removeClass("in").addClass("out");
        });
    } // if

  }); // each
}
```

and test for your self:

**Demo on JsBin**: http://jsbin.com/wewir/1/edit?html,css,js,output

This way it's easier to reuse the feature in the same page or in different pages through your website.